# Inserting data into one table of a many to many relationship and updating linking table

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, razor-pages

I am new to EF Core, I have developing a personal project for learning purposes, I have come across some questions (not necessarily how to code but how to approach the solutions).

One of the questions is:

Scenario: I have an `AppUser` class (inheriting from identity's `User`). `AppUser` can register multiple business and a business can have multiple users (administrators to manage the business), the entity classes have these properties:

`AppUser : IdentityUser` contains a nullable

```
ICollection<Business> Businesses
```

the idea is to register a user at a time and later after verification etc, `User` can add a business.

The `Business` entity has a property

```
ICollection<AppUsers> Users
```

but users is not nullable here, business must at least have a user.

**Note**: in `IEntityTypeConfiguration`, a `.HasMany() .WithMany()` is defined for these entities.

My question is: what is the best practice or way to manage this?

Add business via `Context.Business.Add()` and update the linking table explicitly? (linking table only contains `BusinessId` and `UserId` as foreign keys)

Or would EF Core allow to retrieve related business data via `.Include()` when retrieving from a `User` perspective?

The other (dumb, in my own opinion) way I thought of is to use update on `User` and send the whole user object with business every time a business being added.

Any ideas are appreciated.

./asm

I have tried both above mentioned methods, explicit linking table update worked, with the other method, it seemed not working at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my experience it's better to create the junction table on your own so that you have control over it, not EF.

Let's assume this is your models:

```cs
public class AppUser 
{
    // other props

    public ICollection<UserBusiness> UserBusinesses {get; set;}
}

public class UserBusiness
{
    public long UserId {get; set; }

    public AppUser AppUser {get; set;}

    public long BusinessId {get; set;}

    public Business Business {get; set;}
}

public class Business 
{
    // other props

    public ICollection<UserBusiness> UserBusinesses {get; set;}
}
```

So as you mentioned, first `User` will be added and verified, then can add `Business`, the good thing about **EF** is, it can insert all navigation properties on `Insert`. let me tell you with code:

```cs
var user = await _dbContext.Users.FindAsync(userId);

// add business to user

var userBusiness = new UserBusiness
{
    UserId = user.Id,
    Business = new Business 
    {
        // set business props
    }
}

await _dbContext.UserBusinesses.AddAsync(userBusiness);

// here EF will add a row in the UserBusiness table and another one in Business table
await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
```

by having a junction table in your code, you have the flexibility to add more columns to it, for instance add business expiration means user has this business until next year :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all In your case updating business via user is grabing bunch of unwanted data every time and not so efficient.Secondly You may want to change your code in future and in this case you may need to  make extra effort in refactoring in other word it is code breaking.